# Repeat calculations by subset of data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

Looking to obtain a calculation for each user opposed to the whole data frame from df1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike','Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike','Mike',
                            'Mike', 'Mike','Mike','Mike', 'Mike','Mike', 'Mike', 
                            'Mike','Mike','Mike', 'Mike','Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike',
                            'Mike', 'Mike','Mike'], 
                   'income': [47559,70850,60081,73353,52043,69038,55156,54532,  
                              64937,73780,69577,68116,42777,55733,44923,51096,
                              74317,75160,52160,56356,74077,70007,69407,79659]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Bob', 
                            'Jane', 'Alice','Bob','Jane','Alice','Bob','Jane',
                            'Alice','Bob', 'Jane','Alice','Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice',
                            'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [93426,40594,60920,76683,70643,77195,60496,75527,
                              76784,93686,48243,94225,89828,82593,74815,46937,
                              43372,58319,95770,67525,97085,65901,92556,57715]})

x1 = df['income']


x2 = df1['income'] ### Need this by user opposed to all of df1 'income'
a = max(x1); b = max(x2)
maxval = max(a,b)
c = min(x1); d = min(x2)
minval = max(c,d)

h1, bins= np.histogram(x1, bins = 20, range = (minval, maxval))
h2, _ = np.histogram(x2, bins = 20, range = (minval, maxval))
minval
def return_intersection(h1, h2):
    minima = np.minimum(h1, h2)
    intersection = np.true_divide(np.sum(minima), np.sum(h2))
    return intersection

print(round(return_intersection(h1,h2),2))
```

The end goal is to have overlap calculation for each user in df1 on df:
The actual calculation will differ from the ones below. The numbers below are made up.

```
Bob .54
Jane .67
Alice .28
```

The calculation works, just need it to calculate by user.

Attempted to use but had no luck because the calculation wasn't performing for each user:

```
df1_grouped = df1.groupby('user')
# iterate over each group
for group_name, df_group in df1_grouped:
    for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():
        col = row['income']
```

Comment: `The end goal is to have calculation compared to df (Mike):` What  does this mean? Compare what to what?

Comment: @ExplodingGayFish hi, I made clarifying comments above.

Comment: Can you explain how you get 0.54 for Bob?

Comment: The 0.54 number for Bob is made up. The actual percentage will differ from the made up numbers. The calculation itself works, just need it to be done by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you were doing with your `groupby` code sample since `col` isn't used in your larger codeblock. Here is my guess at what you wanted instead:

```
x1 = df['income']
for key, x2 in df1.groupby('user')['income']:
    maxval = max(x1.max(), x2.max())
    minval = max(x1.min(), x2.min())

    h1, _ = np.histogram(x1, bins=20, range=(minval, maxval))
    h2, _ = np.histogram(x2, bins=20, range=(minval, maxval))

    minima = np.minimum(h1, h2)
    intersection = np.true_divide(np.sum(minima), np.sum(h2))
    print(key, round(intersection, 2))

# Alice 0.25
# Bob 0.38
# Jane 0.43
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing is the code doesn't take into account non-normalized data. The key syntax is useful. Thank again.